# Validating access_token failed, wrong state/nonce

Tags: angular, authentication, openid-connect, angular-oauth2-oidc

I am authenticating using 'angular-oauth2-oidc' with ping federation, authentication is working good in Chrome browser but in Edge we are getting error 'Validating access_token failed, wrong state/nonce. null'. However we see client sending
nonce to ping federation, but ping federation sending back nonce in identity token but not in access token, what could be the issue here? This happens while user authenticating or login. How to resolve any thoughts will be helpful?

Comment: This issue is resolved by disabling the Adobe Flash player in Edge. Hope there is an issue with my Edge Adobe Player.

Comment: I'm getting this in all browsers. Any clue?

Comment: Hi @ONE_FE, Did you find the fix?

Comment: @I.vigneshDavid unfortunately, I don't remember it right now.